# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dark') vuse3 with quasar

Tags: jestjs, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I was trying to do unit test using jest in vue3 with quasar but getting following error

FAIL tests/T1/views/xyz.spec.ts
● Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dark')

i used dark and light mode in quasar to change the background color of screen
but getting error of `dark`
please help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: have you the way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this error running unit tests with vitest in my vuejs 3 + Quasar + vite project. The solution was to add Quasar to the `global.plugins` options in the test suite

```
import { config, mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import MyComponent from './../components/MyComponent.vue';
import { Quasar } from 'quasar';

config.global.plugins = [Quasar];

test('it renders'), () => {
    const wrapper = mount(MyComponent);
};
```